# Skype - can't install it on Freya

Tags: software-installation, skype, dependencies

I am using elementary OS Freya. I was unable to install Skype. I've formatted my laptop and installed Freya (twice), same thing. Can't install Skype, same error:

```
luffy@luffy-Satellite-C850-B797:~$ sudo apt-get install skype
[sudo] password for luffy: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype : Depends: skype-bin but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Update, Additional requested outputs:

- [`grep -r "^deb" /etc/apt/sources.list*`](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/14311073/plain/)
- [`echo q | aptitude -s install skype`](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/14306992/plain/)
- [`apt-get -s -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes install skype-bin`](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/14312254/plain/)
- [`apt-cache policy xdg-user-dirs xdg-user-dirs-gtk xdg-user-dirs:i386 xdg-user-dirs-gtk:i386`](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/14312376/plain/)

Comment: Please [edit] and add output of `sudo apt-get install skype` to question

Comment: Could you provide the output of `apt-cache policy $(apt-rdepends skype 2>/dev/null | grep "^[a-zA-Z]" | sort | paste -s -d" ")` ? BTW, you need to install apt-rdepends , use `sudo apt-get install apt-rdepends`

Comment: tnx @Sneetsher, I did what youve suggested i got this: [Link](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/14307659/plain/)

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/488053/how-to-install-skype-4-3

Comment: tnx @bigbang , Ive tried the suggestions from the link and i got this error -- [link](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/14307781/plain/)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/504693 , especially the "fix-missing" thing...

Comment: @ericb1925 , could you join the chat room [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33691/about-skype-problem)

Comment: guys!.. not only the update error fixed but the Skype was successfully installed in my Freya!.. thanks a million guys!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the normal result (`unmet dependencies`) with `apt-get` when there is a need to remove or replace a package with its other arch. The message is clear in `aptitude` command:

```
  xdg-user-dirs : Conflicts: xdg-user-dirs:i386 but 0.15-1ubuntu3+elementary4~ubuntu14.04.1 is to be installed.
  xdg-user-dirs:i386 : Conflicts: xdg-user-dirs but 0.15-1ubuntu3+elementary4~ubuntu14.04.1 is installed.
```

1. Install xdg-user-dirs-gtk with i386 arch and let it replace amd64 one.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdg-user-dirs-gtk:i386
   ```

   It should remove only two packages and install two. Removes: `xdg-user-dirs-gtk:amd64` & `xdg-user-dirs:amd64` , Installs: `xdg-user-dirs-gtk:i386` & `xdg-user-dirs:i386`
2. Now, install skype

   ```
   sudo apt-get install skype
   ```

   If it doesn't work try to install Skype without recommended packages.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends skype
   ```

   (Usually recommended packages are for medium options)

---

Here the information requested that help debug the problem:

- Check if all repository components and update channels enabled

  ```
  grep -r "^deb" /etc/apt/sources.list*
  ```
- Trace the dependency resolver using apt debug option

  ```
  apt-get -s -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes install skype-bin
  echo q | aptitude -s install skype
  ```
- The available versions of conflict package

  ```
  apt-cache policy xdg-user-dirs xdg-user-dirs-gtk xdg-user-dirs:i386 xdg-user-dirs-gtk:i386
  ```

However, I still think that this a bug in a package dependency.