# Update error (sudo apt-get update)

Tags: updates

I am using freya. When I run sudo apt-get update I got the following errors

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/freya/partner/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/freya/partner/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Total [error](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/14310062/plain/)

Comment: ailed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found thank you so much

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With reference to your other [post](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3774/skype-cant-install-it-on-freya), you have followed [this AU post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343047/installing-skype-on-ubuntu-13-04-64-bit).

To solve the error open terminal and run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:versable/elementary-update
```

For hash sum mismatch run:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Now run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: @ericb1925 ,  Would you accept this answer as it works for you, see https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers . You have power to up vote too :).

Comment: It worked! In the end I could install the latest version of Nodejs!

Comment: I just followed this post.. I hope this works and is proper to do in loki

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if someone still has this problem. Anyway, I solved my problem updating those files:

- `appcenter.list`
- `elementary.list`
- `patches.list`

All files are in `/etc/apt/source.list.d`

And follow instructions from this URL https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1629646