# Software Updater: failed to download repository information

Tags: release-freya, updates, ubuntu

*Currently running on Elementary  OS 0.3.2 freya 64bit*

**Software Updater**

[image: Software Updater]

---

i ran sudo apt-get update and i found some broken packages

```
Fetched 2,550 kB in 7s (328 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/freya/partner/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/freya/partner/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fsvh/pacifica-icon-theme/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fsvh/pacifica-icon-theme/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/freya-getdeb/apps/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 104.28.24.125 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/freya-getdeb/games/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 104.28.24.125 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/freya-getdeb/apps/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 104.28.24.125 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/freya-getdeb/games/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 104.28.24.125 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

from the error lists, does that mean canonical, getdeb and pacifica icon are  down or what?
I've read some other posts and the solution seemed to be removing the ppa s, however i'm afraid that i won't get the updates after removing them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update error (sudo apt-get update)](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3780/update-error-sudo-apt-get-update)

Comment: do i just remove these ppa s? How do i get updates then if i remove them?

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate of that. One of these is a dead PPA, the others are incorrect release versions.

Answer (score 1):

How did you add those repositories? They do not exist (you can check the links in your browser). And I highly doubt that canonical offers packages for freya ;)

Use the trusty packages for the canonical and getdeb repositories. The launchpad repository hasn't been updated since 2013 so it doesn't provide any trusty packages.

Comment: how exactly do i do that?

Comment: Look in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and replace any instances of `freya` with `trusty`