# Getting errors when trying to run sudo apt-get update

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-terminal

So I'm  having the following issues

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu loki Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu loki Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu/dists/loki/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu/dists/loki/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

can anyone tell me what's going on? I did a clean install of loki.

I wanted to try the solution from [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3780/update-error-sudo-apt-get-update) but it's not applicable exactly for my situation and I didn't know how to alter it for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The elementary PPAs use the underlying Ubuntu release names rather than the elementary release name (see [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu/dists/)).

For some reason your system is trying to fetch packages from http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu/dists/loki instead of http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu/dists/xenial (Loki is based on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus) ). You can rectify this by modifying `/etc/apt/sources.list` and replacing occurrences of `ubuntu/dists/loki` with `ubuntu/dists/xenial` and then re-running `sudo apt update`.

Quite *why* this has happened I am unsure. You should file a bug report about it on Launchpad.

Comment: In my sources.list it doesn't have any mention of loki. But in software and updates I see it a couple times. And there is no http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu/dists/loki or  http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu/dists/xenial

lsb_release -sc outputs loki though

Comment: I overwrote my sources.list with one I generated using https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/generate.php and no longer am I getting errors.

Comment: @nightspades if you keep messing with your sources, you'll keep getting errors like these.

Comment: Glad you managed to find a workaround - but you might still want to try and get to the bottom of *why* the problem arose in the first place to avoid it in the future. Could you post the contents of your original `sources.list`?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem (sources.list below).  I created a USB Live using Unetbootin (on a Mac).

```
deb cdrom:[elementary OS 0.4 _Loki_ - Stable amd64 (20160909)]/ xenial contrib main non-free
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

I found a solution: I commented out the first line of the `sources.list` (the CD-ROM one). I was also getting appstream errors, so I followed this workaround: http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1601971

Update: sources.list keeps adding the offending line again, so i keep having to edit sources.list to fix it.  Should I log this as a bug?

Comment: How do I stop the `deb cdrom` line being added to sources.list?  What keeps writing that line to the file?

Answer (score 0):

the elementary list is in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary.list

the changes will be also happen in patches; /etc/apt/sources.list.d/patches.list
there are also loki Release need to be replace by xenial

Comment: A little more context here would make this answer more reusable for future readers

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if someone still has this problem. Anyway, I solved my problem updating those files:

- appcenter.list
- elementary.list
- patches.list

All files are in /etc/apt/source.list.d

And follow instructions from this URL https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1629646