# Error while doing 'sudo apt update': no Release file

Tags: release-loki, apt

Whenever I do `sudo apt update`, I get the following response:

```
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu loki InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                      
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]                                                                                               
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu loki InRelease                                                                                            
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]                                                
Ign:6 http://http.kali.org/kali loki InRelease                                                                                       
Ign:7 http://security.kali.org/kali-security loki InRelease                                                                          
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu loki Release                                         
  404  Not Found
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu loki Release                                     
  404  Not Found
Err:10 http://http.kali.org/kali loki Release                                                                   
  404  Not Found
Err:11 http://security.kali.org/kali-security loki Release                                              
  404  Not Found
Get:12 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]    
Reading package lists... Done      
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu loki Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu loki Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali loki Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.kali.org/kali-security loki Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I'm able to do `sudo apt upgrade` and everything seems to work fine but this bugs me a lot.

I found similar questions in the forum but nothing with this exact issue.

I thought this [answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/7830/11882) would solve the issue for me but there are no `ubuntu/dists/loki` in my `/etc/apt/sources.list` to replace with `ubuntu/dists/xenial`.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: Please remove anything Kali-related on your sources if you want to keep your system stable (Kali repositories are only compatible with Kali linux). Kali is based on Debian testing so no way would you make it compatible on Ubuntu-based distros. I recommend using the Kali docker image if you needed the tools on elementary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting errors when trying to run sudo apt-get update](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7763/getting-errors-when-trying-to-run-sudo-apt-get-update)

Comment: it's a bug already posted in 2016: https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1629646

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click on the Files icon in Plank dock, select *New Window As Administrator*, go to */etc/apt/sources.list.d/* folder and edit the various files there related to each of the errors by changing references from *loki* release to *xenial* release.

Otherwise,  delete the kali repository file, because there isn't a *loki* or *xenial* release for it. Kali is a Debian based distro.

Then try again with

```
sudo apt update
```

---

Update in relation with similar occurrences:

This might be related to more than just [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1629646) bug. I have seen a similar error in third party ppa-s where instead of "xenial" was written "bionic" resulting in a similar error with ha similar fix.

Comment: You're welcome Bilesh Ganguly

Answer (score 3):

I do not have enough rep to comment on answers. So here it goes. That oneliner does the trick for you or anyone in same situation

```
find /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ -type f -exec sed -i.bak -e 's/loki/xenial/' '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 1):

@bitseater's answer should fix the issue, but to get to the bottom of this issue I would recommend people experiencing this issue to help out in the following issue:
https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/565
More information on what might have caused the issue would be very welcome.

Comment: I, too, support corralling our efforts together as @peter-uithoven directs. GitHub issue [AppCenter#565](https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/565) is closed (and dated) so I filed a new issue [os#316](https://github.com/elementary/os/issues/316) to help address the severity of the issue in the current 5.1 (Hera) release: 1. it stops security updates from being received upon fresh install and 2. does not easily enable new developers who wish to contribute get through [our Develo