# Missing release files during apt update

Tags: release-loki, updates, apt

I will post it here, since I cannot find chat to ask a question or any specific place to post bugs. Sorry, if it's wrong place to post such bug, redirect me in right direction please.

#### My setup

Freshly (10.01.2018) downloaded and installed elementary os. No additional PPAs. After installation my work've been:

`apt update; apt upgrade; apt install chromium-browser firefox mc pydf grc zsh git transmission; dpkg -i ~/Downloads/slack.deb ; apt install -f; apt autoremove`

So, I have pretty standard system.

#### Problem

`apt update` leads to

```
--- ~ » sudo apt update                                                                                                               100 ↵
Hit:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                                                         
Hit:3 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                                                                       
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu loki InRelease                                                                  
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                             
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu loki InRelease                      
Ign:7 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter loki InRelease                                       
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu loki Release                            
  404  Not Found
Err:9 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter loki Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 104.28.5.44 80]
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu loki Release
  404  Not Found
Hit:11 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Reading package lists... Done 
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu loki Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter loki Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu loki Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Problem is here:

```
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu loki Release                            
  404  Not Found
Err:9 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter loki Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 104.28.5.44 80]
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu loki Release
  404  Not Found
```

#### My hypotesis

`cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary.list`

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu loki main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu loki main
```

There should be `xenial` instead of `loki`. Same goes for

- `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list`
- `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/patches.list`

#### Taken actions

I've done this `find /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ -type f -exec sed -i.bak -e 's/loki/xenial/' '{}' \;`
Then `apt upgrade`. Below lies output of `apt upgrade`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  indicator-bluetooth indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard indicator-power indicator-sound liburl-dispatcher1 libvala-0.34-0
  ubuntu-touch-sounds
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libvala-0.36-0
The following packages have been kept back:
  appcenter audience capnet-assist gala libgala0 libmaya-calendar0 libnoise-core0 libpantheon-files-core0 libpantheon-files-widgets0
  maya-calendar maya-calendar-daemon maya-calendar-plugin-caldav maya-calendar-plugin-google noise pantheon-calculator pantheon-files
  pantheon-greeter pantheon-mail pantheon-photos pantheon-photos-common pantheon-terminal screenshot-tool slingshot-launcher
  snap-photobooth user-specific-alternatives
The following packages will be upgraded:
  base-files bash cerbere contractor dkms elementary-icon-theme elementary-theme evince evince-common hicolor-icon-theme libevdocument3-4
  libevview3-3 libgranite-common libnm-gtk-common libnm-gtk0 libnma-common libnma0 libpantheon-online-accounts0 libscratchcore0
  libunity-control-center1 libwingpanel-2.0-0 network-manager-gnome pantheon-agent-polkit pantheon-online-accounts-plugin-fastmail
  pantheon-online-accounts-plugin-password pantheon-print scratch-text-editor switchboard-plug-about switchboard-plug-networking
  switchboard-plug-notifications switchboard-plug-online-accounts switchboard-plug-useraccounts switchboard-plug-users
  unity-control-center unity-control-center-faces wingpanel wingpanel-indicator-bluetooth wingpanel-indicator-network
38 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 25 not upgraded.
Need to get 13,4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 20,9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

Many packages with names `pantheon-*`, `switchboard-*`, `*gala*`, `*vala*` etc, lead me to think, that this is correct decision.

#### Question

Is my actions from previous section is the right ones? Am I safe to upgrade? (I think so). If that's the case - should I report it somewhere else? Make a simple PR? (cannot find related repo though)

Comment: If what you did helped, it would be very interesting to share that in an older, similar question: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/13060/error-while-doing-sudo-apt-update

Comment: hi @PeterUithoven. yea, my `find /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ -type f -exec sed -i.bak -e 's/loki/xenial/' '{}' \;` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I checked my version of the two files. And both contain the line:
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu xenial main

The elementary.list file also have a deb-src line. 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu xenial main

I have not edited these files myself at any point, so this should be the out-of-box version.
I will guess that you are correct and it is safe to upgrade.