# Unable to update / PPA unsigned after fresh install - Hera

Tags: updates, appcenter, release-hera, ppa

I have installed elementary OS previously without issues. I wanted to try the latest issue and get the following issue when i check on terminal and following a couple of google searches:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found this link in my searches:
[Error while doing 'sudo apt update': no Release file](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/13060/error-while-doing-sudo-apt-update-no-release-file)

I was able to do apt upgrade.

App-center still doesn't work

***Update***
edit appcenter, elementary and patches .list flies - remove any refrence to Hera / Juno to Bionic and save.

Everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Try reboot , some reason this worked for me. I had issue few times after installing apps via terminal