# Hash Sum Mismatch Error

Tags: apt

I am getting a hash sum mismatch error.

I have several ppa's hopefully this is not the cause.
tweaks, libreoffice, and caffeine, vivaldi, opera

I followed the instructions [Update error (sudo apt-get update)](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3780/update-error-sudo-apt-get-update)

Please let me know if this was dumb for me to delete these repos in the instructions above which did not work.

Here is a list of the updates errors.
I am having problems installing the printer driver and I think it needs these 386 files.

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/2fbf9e0fb860af69bb1c3d80156d44eeeac56ea04ab25784edb33dca8e13849e  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/3602ddd1416465512c9ec028996dc7eb5b1ab2d271e26a4fe445415cad36262b  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/5532eca052512fed6ea5f36971ad74b0b052d9faa1b448913acf67b3475cd29a  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/821d5d66cf4b825ca62d92e25e953f46981e588e4fbff66fe23f8dabd51cd1ad  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Please execute these commands in the terminal, and let me know what if you find.

    `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`  
    `sudo apt-get update`  
    `sudo apt-get clean`  
    `sudo apt-get install --fix-missing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem a week ago
Here's what I did.
Install "Additional Drivers" from the Appcenter
[image]
Open the **additional drivers** and Click on the **Ubuntu Software** tab and click Others as mentioned below
[image]
Click "**Select Best server**" and wait for the network to detect best server and click "**choose server**"
[image]

Comment: Thanks.. I forgot to update my own question with the answer I found.  Similar to yours.. change the archive location.  I had switched it from myanmar to main server which caused the error.  USA is pretty good.  Maybe I will go back to Myanmar server.

Answer (score 1):

That is because of cached metadata. Executing the following command on terminal will delete your cached metadata and re-download them,
`sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get clean`

And I suggested `sudo apt-get install --fix-missing` on comment as a bonus to install / fix any broken package, but this was not necessary for your problem I think.